# How do I determine what version of Thunderbird is running on my Ubuntu 16.4.1?

Tags: thunderbird, email

How do I determine what version of Thunderbird is running on my Ubuntu 16.4.1? I just built an old machine (PC) in installed the latest Ubuntu, found the Thunderbird email app, and saw if I wanted it in sync with my gmail, it had to be a certain version. Now I'm signed up and just need to find if I have a/the compatible correct version. I'm going to keep looking, just thought I'd get a quick answer.

Comment: Thank you .  My output was different than yours either as user or root, but either way the output was Thunderbird 45.2.0.  Thank you very much--saved me a lot of time probably.

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Fire up a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following command:

```
thunderbird --version
```

The output I got was:

```
(process:3718): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
 Thunderbird 38.4.0
```

So you can see my system has Thunderbird version `38.4.0`.

---

Alternatively, a GUI way is to open Thunderbird and go `Help > About Thunderbird`. I get this window, which shows the version:
[image]

Comment: FYI since you're new here, if my answer was helpful, you can upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the version number in the prefs.js file, open that in a text editor and look for the line containing "extensions.lastAppVersion"